# How to find peak to peak and rms current for square wave AC circuit?

Tags: resistors, ac, current-measurement, impedance

I have a circuit with AC square wave at 10V and 4 Hz. There is only a single resistor of 1000 ohm in the circuit. I would like to calculate the rms current and also the peak to peak current of this circuit.

Comment: seems like a school assignment ... please show your work that you have done so far

Comment: It is not a school assignment. Am on DIY circuit. Am new to electronics

Comment: Draw waveforms, search on how to find rms and average value of any signal

Comment: @iamnamrud: Have a look at my answer to https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/356562/ac-effect-value/356611#356611 and see if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

> I have a circuit with AC square wave at 10V and 4 Hz. There is only a
>   single resistor of 1000 ohm in the circuit. I would like to calculate
>   the rms current and also the peak to peak current of this circuit.

[image]

- So calculate RMS current based on the peak voltage of 10 volts and 1000 ohms.
- The peak current is also the same as the RMS current
- The peak to peak current is twice the peak current.

Answer (score 0):

The peak can be found by using:

$$\text{V}_\text{R}=\text{V}_\text{in}=\text{I}_\text{R}\cdot\text{R}=\text{I}_\text{in}\cdot\text{R}\tag1$$

And the RMS can be found by finding:

$$\frac{1}{100}=\overline{\text{I}}_\text{R}=\overline{\text{I}}_\text{in}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{\frac{1}{4}-0}\int_0^\frac{1}{4}\text{I}_\text{R}^2\space\text{d}x}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{\frac{1}{4}-0}\int_0^\frac{1}{4}\text{I}_\text{in}^2\space\text{d}x}=$$
$$\sqrt{\frac{1}{\frac{1}{4}-0}\int_0^\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{\text{V}_\text{R}}{\text{R}}\right)^2\space\text{d}x}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{\frac{1}{4}-0}\int_0^\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{\text{V}_\text{in}}{\text{R}}\right)^2\space\text{d}x}\tag2$$

Comment: The frequency doesn't matter?

Comment: @iamnamrud It does, where do you think that the \$\frac{1}{4}\$ comes from?!

Comment: Compensated for down vote...