# How to calculate RMS value for current square wave?

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, switch-mode-power-supply, buck

How do I calculate the RMS value for the current waveform during a transient event like the picture below?

Assuming:
I<sub>x</sub> = 6 A
I<sub>y</sub> = 38 A
duty cycle = 38%
frequency = unknown

My goal is to know what the behavior of the voltage regulator of a CPU (AMD/Intel) is under transient load.

[image]

Comment: See [ac-effect-value](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/356562/ac-effect-value/356611#356611) for an answer to a similar question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AC Effect Value](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/356562/ac-effect-value)

Answer (score 3):

root of mean of squared current, thus:

$$RMS= \sqrt{ 0.38 I_x^2 + 0.62 I_y^2 } $$